# Why am I getting a 404 error with ng-src even though image is appearing?

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying an image with `ng-src`:

`<img style="width: 100px" ng-src="{{absolutePath}}customImages/{{currentBook.idcode}}.png"/>`

which is found and displays fine, however in Firebug console, I am getting this error:

`NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/learntracker/customImages/.png"`

as if this is being executed before the variables exist.

This HTML code exists inside a `<div ng-cloak ng-app="mainModule">` and `ng-cloak` I understand to stop any executing before the variables exist.

**Why is this error occurring and how can I suppress it?**

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you might be loading the data which populates `currentBook` object asynchronously. So during the previous digest cycle, `ng-src` directive would have rendered the src for the image with no value for `currentBook.idcode` and once it gets populated on the scope, another digest cycle runs updating the image. So the previous causes the 404. You could place an `ng-if` on the image.

ex:-

```
<img style="width: 100px" ng-if="currentBook.idcode" 
     ng-src="{{absolutePath}}customImages/{{currentBook.idcode}}.png"/>
```

You could see an small demo implementation **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DatIM1ImHxtIV53l4m1p?p=preview)**

*But this seems to have been fixed with 1.3.x version of angular*, in-order to prevent rendering of image src before all the interpolations are expanded to get values. **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JnhVt0aTv0ZhRWVHxmre?p=preview)**

[`ng-cloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is only helpful not to expose interpolation expression briefly while the angular is loading.

---

Some additional info (Courtesy @zeroflagL ) :

With angular version 1.3.x ng-src makes use of all or nothing interpolation ([feature addition to interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate#usage)), meaning it will not expand the directive unless all the bound interpolations are resolved. You can see this mapping in the [compile provider source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1eb6036d29687f7b675ff5b28f6cbf105fcb611b/src/ng/compile.js#L707).

```
ALL_OR_NOTHING_ATTRS = makeMap('ngSrc,ngSrcset,src,srcset'),
```

Comment: To complement your great answer: `$interpolate` supports the optional argument `allOrNothing`, which is used by `ngSrc`. If it's `true` then `$interpolate` returns `undefined` unless all expressions have a value.

Comment: @zeroflagL awesome, Yeah that is a great information to add. Thank you!!.  `ALL_OR_NOTHING_ATTRS = makeMap('ngSrc,ngSrcset,src,srcset'),`

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do in this case is to actually have a function on scope that creates the ULR for the image path:

```
<img style="width: 100px" ng-if="currentBook.idcode" ng-src="getImagePath(currentBook.idcode)">


var absolutePath = 'somepath/';
$scope.getImagePath = function(idcode) {
    return absolutePath + 'customImages/' + idcode + '.png';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is possible to call a function from ng-src?

Comment: It was at the time of this post.  Not sure if anything has changed as I have been out of the ng-world for a while.